# incompatible p:commandButton with updating values in xhtml file

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

Today I have spent all day trying to understand why values in xhtml file were not updated after calling a bean from a `<p:commandButton>`.

After I changed the p:commandButton for h:commandButton everything worked fine. This is how I declared the commandButton:

```
<p:commandButton id="b1" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="a"
    action="#{turnoController.createTurno('a')}"
    onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
```

With this command button it refreshes but I dont know how to disable it.

```
<h:commandButton id="b1" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="a"
    action="#{turnoController.createTurno('a')}"/>
```

I want to ask why is the p:commandButton incompatible with "refreshing" the values of the page???

What I want to do is to turn the buttons disabled after clicking but also to update all values...

How can I make it in xhtml+jsf???

Comment: Try using `update="@form"` and `oncomplete="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=false;"`.

Comment: oncomplete... doesnt work

Comment: omg! i've noticed that it is the <p:commandButton who doesn't let me refresh the values.... not the click option... It works with <h:commandButton ¡( but I don't know how to disable it

Comment: I've post an answer in your so long previous question treating this problem also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onclick` is not incompatible with refreshing values of the page. The reason the update is failing is that your `onclick` function probably ends up setting the `<p:commandButton disabled="true"/>` before the request gets to the `APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES` phase. This is the phase in the JSF lifecycle where component properties are evaluated and stored as part of the component's personal map of attributes

A property with `disabled="true"` will be ignored by JSF during processing and that's the result you're observing. `onclick` is simply too early to disable the button.

Use ajax to update the button's disabled property to save yourself the stress:

```
<p:commandButton id="b1" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="a"
               action="#{turnoController.createTurno('a')}" disabled="#{bean.isButtonEnabled}" >
  <f:event name="postValidate" listener="#{bean.disableButton}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

Where `buttonEnabled` is a property you'll define on your managed bean and `disableButton` is a method in your managed bean that toggles the state of the `buttonEnabled` variable. I've chosen the `postValidate` event phase of the component because it's after the `APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES` JSF phase and it's safe to assume disabling your button at this point will have no negative effects.

As an alternative, you could try the following option, if you're interested in a client-side only solution:

- [How to prevent from user from clicking button twice(JSF command button not performing action if onclick property specified)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841948/how-to-prevent-from-user-from-clicking-button-twicejsf-command-button-not-perfo)

Comment: i'll try to do it with ajax ;)

Comment: I'm doing it your way...  but I have a little question: how do I recognize in the bean which button is calling???

Comment: I've found a very simple way to set the disabled option... thanks for the idea!!!!!

Comment: @dak, please share here. You can retrieve the calling button by adding an argument of type `ComponentSystemEvent` to the `disableButton` method and calling `getComponent` on the argument